# Вывод объектов из файла

Tags: java, файлы, объекты

Изучаю ввод/вывод данных, но не совсем понятно(а может и совсем не понятно) как работать с объектами. Возможно кто-то подскажет и объяснит как это работает? Есть файл в котором записаны некоторые объекты(точнее наверное их поля). Как на примере:

```
name : "name"
secondName : "secondName"
heigtn : 180
age : 30

name : "name2"
secondName : "secondName2"
heigtn : 185
age : 32

name : "name3"
secondName : "secondName3"
heigtn : 190
age : 20
```

Стоит задача вывести все эти объекты(поля) в наш код, произвести с ними разные операции (по типу: кто выше, кто старше и т.п.) и результат записать в другой файл.
У меня проблема с выводом и вводом объектов! Все мои попытки - приводят к Exception разного типа. Возможно, кто-то научит и объяснит как правильно поступать в этом случае, и покажет на моем примере как это делать, потому что в интернете не нашел примеров похожих на мой случай или же их не понял.
Если это поможет делу - то я делал класс с конструктором для этих объектов и имплементировал Serializable.

Comment: Вам обязательно использовать именно представленный формат файла?  Или можете исправить файл, чтобы он соответствовал формату JSON или YAML?  Тогда можно было бы использовать стандартные библиотеки типа Jackson для чтения такого файла.  Иначе вам придётся писать свой мини-парсер: объекты разделяются двумя пустыми строками, в каждой строке записана пара "ключ-значение".

Comment: Сейчас почитаю что такое  JSON, YAML. Возможно  тогда исправлю файл. Спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: В моем случае нужно работать именно с таким представлением файла.

Comment: Возможно вытянуть данные с помощью RandomAccessFile? что-бы код  не выглядел огромным?

Comment: Как вы должны сохранять прочитанные объекты?  Вы уже учили коллекции типа списка?

Comment: Читать файл построчно можно разными способами, в том числе и обычным сканером, не уверен, что `RandomAccessFile` наиболее подходящий или имеет какие-то серьезные преимущества

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим, имеется некий класс `Person` со строковыми полями `name`, `secondName` и целочисленными полями `height`, `age`, и текстовый файл указанного формата.   Признаком конца объекта в файле служит пустая строка.

Далее, прочитанные объекты будут добавляться в соответствующий список `List<Person> persons`.

Итак, начинаем читать файл построчно -- для простоты, при помощи сканера `Scanner::nextLine`.  Заводим несколько переменных, аналогичных полям объекта.  Если строка непустая, разбиваем её по  `"\\s*:\\s*"` (двоеточие с опциональными пробелами вокруг него) на пару "ключ - значение", и в зависимости от ключа запоминаем значение в соответствующей переменной при помощи оператора `switch`.

Как только обнаружена пустая строка (нашли конец объекта), создаем новый экземпляр с известными полями и добавляем её в коллекцию (список).

Примерная реализация в виде метода, принимающего имя файла и возвращающего список объектов:

```java
public static List<Person> readPersons(String fileName) throws IOException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    String name = null, secondName = null;
    int age = 0, height = 0;
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        // читаем строку, удаляя пробелы из её начала и конца
        String line = scan.nextLine().trim(); 

        if (line.isEmpty()) { // нашли пустую строку конец объекта
            if (name != null && secondName != null && age > 0 && height > 0) {
                // все поля прочитаны, создаем и добавляем экземпляр
                persons.add(new Person(name, secondName, age, height));
                // "сброс" полей
                name = secondName = null;
                age = height = 0;
            }
            continue;
        }
        // обработка отдельных полей
        // разбиваем по двоеточию на пару ключ - значение
        String[] keyValue = line.split("\\s*:\\s*");
        switch (keyValue[0]) {
            "name" -> name = keyValue[1];
            "secondName" -> secondName = keyValue[1];
            "age" -> age = Integer.parseInt(keyValue[1]);
            "height" -> height = Integer.parseInt(keyValue[1]);
            default -> System.out.println("Нашли неизвестное поле '" + keyValue[0] + "'");
        }
    }
    return persons; 
}
```

---

Возможно, понадобится дополнительно убрать пару кавычек из строковых значений:

```java
public static stripQuotes(String str) {
    return str == null || str.length() < 2 
        ? str 
        : str.startsWith("\"") && str.endsWith("\"") 
            ? str.substring(1, str.length() - 1)
            : str;
}
```

тогда его придётся вызвать так:

```java
        switch (keyValue[0]) {
            "name" -> name = stripQuotes(keyValue[1]);
            "secondName" -> secondName = stripQuotes(keyValue[1]);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Пример более чем наглядный и понятный!